# Obtain x,y coords of individual Chars in a SWT text widget

Tags: java, swt, gdi

If I write a text on SWT say "this text" in a particular font/style , I want the individual coords of 't' 'h' 'i' 's' and so on. Is there any way to obtain the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
text.setText("This");

GC gc = new GC(text);
int currentPixelsX = text.getBounds().x;
int currentPixelsY = text.getBounds().y;
for (int i = 0; i < text.getText().length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("X co-ordinate of " + text.getText().charAt(i) + ":" + currentPixelsX);
    System.out.println("Y co-ordinate of " + text.getText().charAt(i) + ":" + currentPixelsY);

    currentPixelsX = currentPixelsX + gc.getCharWidth(text.getText().charAt(i));
}
```

This gives the the pixel co-ordinates with respect to the parent of the text box.

Comment: The solution you are suggesting does not accomodate for char spacing/word spacing adjustments of GDI.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0300__SWT-2D-Graphics/MeasureaString.htm) Snippet can help you calculating the individual length of a character